# Problems with jquery Table sorter on my table, I recieve wall of json text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 on my project.

I have a view with a bunch of DDL's, Search Button and a Table.
User can choose values and then hit the search button and the table will show all data that got hit.

This is my jquery code for the search button click:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#submitfloat').click(function () {
            var SubjectTypes = $('#SubjectTypes').val();
            var Teams = $('#Teams').val();
            var Companies = $('#Companies').val();
            var Consultants = $('#Consultants').val();
            var PlannedDates = $('#PlannedDates').val();
            var CompletedDates = $('#CompletedDates').val();
            var DateTypes = $('#DateTypes').val();
            var data = {
                Subjectypes: SubjectTypes,
                Companies: Companies,
                Teams: Teams,
                Consultants: Consultants,
                PlannedDates: PlannedDates,
                CompletedDates: CompletedDates,
                DateTypes: DateTypes
            };

                $.post('@Url.Action("Search", "SearchNKI")', data, function (result) {
                    $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").html('');
                    result.forEach(function (goalcard) {
                        $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").append(
                            $('<tr/>', {
                                click: function () {
                                    // todo: redirect
                                    alert(goalcard.Id);
                                },
                                html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name + "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer + "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate + "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + "</td>"
                            }));
                    });
                });
                return false;
        });
    });
```

This is my Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Search(SearchQueryViewModel model)
 {
     var goalcard = SearchRep.FindGoalCard(model); // My LINQ

     return Json(goalcard.Select(x => new GoalCardViewModel(x)));
 }
```

Everything works fine but when I add my Jquery Table Sorter:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#GoalcardSearchResult").tablesorter();
        }); 
    </script>
```

I get this wall of Json text when I click on the Search button:

![][1]

[1]:

I have no idea why this happens, when I debug my search button click jquery code its not even getting executed when I add the Table Sorter jquery code. Anyone have any idea what the cause is?

All I know is that when I add the Table Sorter, it blocks my button click jquery code from running and jumps directly to the server-side and returns json.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend using `empty()` instead of `html('')` since it makes more sense for people who don't know the code. Is there a reason you are you binding the click function in each result, instead of using live/delegate? It's hard do debug, but i would guess there is a bug in the append function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a modified Table Sorter code, with some minor changes I got it running